# error TS2345: Argument of type '{ read: typeof ElementRef; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; static: boolean; }'

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

So I'm upgrading my Angular app from 7 to 8, when I run `ng serve`, I get this following error:

```
error TS2739: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'EmployeeModel': statut, hasLaws, disablePlanningManagerOrLeaderOrFixe

303         this.employee = {...this.employee, ...entry[1]};
```

In my Typescript file:

```
getEmployeeDetail() {
    this.setIdSecuriteSocialAndIdBanqueToEmployeeBefore();
    Object.entries(this.infosPersonnellesForm.value).forEach(entry => {
      if (entry[0] === 'coordonnees' || entry[0] === 'divers') {
        this.employee = {...this.employee, ...entry[1]};
      } else {
        this.employee[entry[0]] = entry[1];
      }
    });
    this.setIdSecuriteSocialAndIdBanqueToEmployeeAfter();

  }
```

Anyone knows how to solve this issue ? Thank you

Comment: `EmployeeModel` is missing `status, hasLow, disablePlanningManagerOrLeaderOrFixe`.
Add these properties to `EmployeeModel`  Interface.

Comment: `this.employee = {...this.employee, ...entry[1]};` here `entry[1]` must be containing the above 3 properties. when you de-structure it` this.employee` is not having these properties and typescript is throwing this error.

Comment: Apparently `entry[1]` (respectively the form) is empty when you call this function, so you might either call this function at the wrong moment or you need to add some additional checks to make sure your form has actually the required values (or make the properties optional).

Comment: `infosPersonnellesForm.value` what are the formControls for this FormGroup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved the issue by recognizing that `status, hasLow, disablePlanningManagerOrLeaderOrFixe` have not been set as `optional parameters` yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have not paste the full code, according to the error you should update the @ViewChild according to below syntax.

Before:

```
@ViewChild('foo') foo: ElementRef;
```

After:

```
// query results available in ngOnInit
@ViewChild('foo', {static: true}) foo: ElementRef;

OR

// query results available in ngAfterViewInit
@ViewChild('foo', {static: false}) foo: ElementRef;
```